# Group by date, without the time included BUT keep date as one entry

Tags: sql, group-by

Hello I've seen similar questions to mine which i've tried to follow but without much success so thought i'd try as a separate question. Im new to Stack Overflow and new to SQL so apologies if this wasn't the right thing to do. I've followed some previous responses where answers have been given in order to group by a datetime column without including the time portion but when I run the code, although it works, it still adds the date as 2 separate entries even though its on the same date. My code is as follows:

```
SELECT CAST(b.UPSRT_DTTM AS DATE), COUNT(b.cnsmr_id) AS NumberofTimes
FROM UDEFCAT_YOUR_BUDGET b
WHERE b.UPSRT_DTTM >= '2020-01-01' AND Cnsmr_id = '600130'
GROUP BY b.UPSRT_DTTM
```

My outcome is as follows:

| (No column name) | NumberofTimes |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-21 | 1 |
| 2021-05-20 | 1 |
| 2021-05-20 | 1 |

As you can see, there are 2 entries for the 20th May 2021 but I expected to see this as one entry with a count of two.

I hope that makes sense! I've looked around on here but can't find this exact issue. Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You group by a datetime, so you get one result row per datetime. In the select clause you say that you don't want to see the time of the datetime in your result list, so you don't see it. What you want instead is one row per *date*, so group by date.

Comment: BTW: It helps readabilty to stay consistent with uper/lower case. You should also use the appropriate data types for literals: `SELECT CAST(b.upsrt_dttm AS DATE), COUNT(b.cnsmr_id) AS number_of_times FROM udefcat_your_budget b WHERE b.upsrt_dttm >= DATE '2020-01-01' AND cnsmr_id = 600130 GROUP BY CAST(b.upsrt_dttm AS DATE) ORDER BY CAST(b.upsrt_dttm AS DATE);`. (You haven't tagged your request with your DBMS, so I used the standard SQL date literal syntax.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column would clearly have a time component (based on the name).  Try aggregating on the *date* component:

```
SELECT CAST(b.UPSRT_DTTM AS DATE), COUNT(b.cnsmr_id) AS NumberofTimes
FROM UDEFCAT_YOUR_BUDGET b
WHERE b.UPSRT_DTTM >= '2020-01-01' AND Cnsmr_id = '600130'
GROUP BY CAST(b.UPSRT_DTTM AS DATE);
```

Comment: Thank you! I genuinely thought I had tried this but it didn't work at all. But I copied what you've just answered and it worked perfectly so I must have just got bogged down trying multiple things and it must have been a variation of this but not this exactly!  Feel a bit silly now but thank you for the super speedy response!

Answer (score 1):

You need to you the same date field in your groupby. You're using a datetime field in groupby. And hence it is grouping it by date and time as well for 2021-05-20

2021-05-20 has two instance in the table with different time and hence it came up twice in the output.
2020-12-21  has one instance for a time and hence it came up just once.

```
SELECT CAST(b.UPSRT_DTTM AS DATE), COUNT(b.cnsmr_id) AS NumberofTimes
FROM UDEFCAT_YOUR_BUDGET b WHERE b.UPSRT_DTTM >= '2020-01-01' AND Cnsmr_id = '600130'
GROUP BY CAST(b.UPSRT_DTTM AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the same CAST function when you use the field in group by.

```
SELECT CAST(b.UPSRT_DTTM AS DATE), COUNT(b.cnsmr_id) AS NumberofTimes
FROM UDEFCAT_YOUR_BUDGET b
WHERE b.UPSRT_DTTM >= '2020-01-01' AND Cnsmr_id = '600130'
GROUP BY CAST(b.UPSRT_DTTM AS DATE)
```